# How can I compare an array to another array that has a nested array to find matching results?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Each user in our database can have specific skills. We have a list of available skills in our db and each has it's own unique id. We need to be able to filter users to see which ones have the skill we are looking for. For example, show all Janitors.

We're using vuejs and this filter is a computed property.

Here's what I have so far:

```
filteredResults() {
  return this.user.filter(user => this.skills.find(skill => user.skills.id == skills.id));
}
```

I think this is my problem "user.skills.id". I want to say: user.skills[*].id, but that's not valid syntax.

How can I find my users where one of their skills has an id that matches my selected (in a search dropdown) skill.id?

Our data looks like this:

```
Users: [
  user1: {
    name: "Tom",
    id: "12345",
    skills: [
      0: {
        title: "Programmer",
        id: "12345678"
        },
      1: {
        title: "Janitor",
        id: "6788012"
       }
    ]
  },
  user2 {
    name: "Bill",
    id: "u0wb0fu3b",
    skills: [
      0: {
        title: "Landscaper",
        id: "234525"
      },
      1: {
        title: "Janitor",
        id: "6788012"
      }
    ]
  }
]
SearchedSkills: [
  0: {
      title: "Landscaper",
      id: "234525"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const expected_id = SearchedSkills[0].id
    let filtered_users = []

    for (const user of Users) {
        if (user.id === expected_id)
            filtered_users.push(user)
    }
    console.log(filtered_users)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
return this.user.filter(user => this.skills.some(
        skill => user.skills.some(({id}) => id === skill.id)));
```

Comment: [Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/odqrn192/)

Comment: Getting this Error: user.skills.some is not a function

Comment: @GregFielding Have you checked the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/odqrn192/) I provided? You can see that it works fine. The error is likely elsewhere in your code or data.

Comment: There may be some instances in our data where user.skills in not an array. Is there a way to add a typeOf check in your function to only filter valid arrays?

Comment: @GregFielding Sure: `Array.isArray(user.skills) && user.skills.some(({id}) => id === skill.id)`

Comment: Alternatively, if `user.skills` has a `some` property iff it's an array, then you could simply use `user.skills.some?.(({id}) => id === skill.id)`